# Kohana Authlite - not allow two users logged in ith the same credentials the same session

Tags: authentication, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

i am using authlite authentication module for my kohana 3 website. Now it is possible for two users to login using the same credentials, in the same session. i don't want this to happen for security reasons.

is there any possibility for me to avoid it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Auth does not do that sort of a check for you.  If you want that, you'll need to overwrite the function that does the token generation and add some code to:

1. keep records of who is logged in
2. check login against the list of previous user->token records and log old ones out
3. assign new token